# Как срезать подматрицу из двумерного массива NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

Допустим есть массив размером 50х50.

```
Array = np.zeros((50, 50), dtype=np.int8)
```

Как мне вырезать из из него матрицу размером 10х10 с конкретного индекса этого массива (например, начиная с 10 ряда и 3 колонки)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делайте так как описали в вопросе:

```
res = Array[10:10+10, 3:3+10]
```

PS индексация в Numpy как и в Vanilla Python начинается с нуля, поэтому если под десятой строкой подразумевается строка с индексом 9, то и индексы надо соответственно адаптировать:

```
res = Array[9:9+10, 2:2+10]
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: А можно ли делать срез, задав начальные и конечные координаты? Или просто нужно из конечных вычесть начальные (чтобы получить дельты) и потом их прибавлять к соответствующим осям как в вашем примере?